# Using jasmine to test internally called functions in other modules?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, ecmascript-6

So I have a situation where I have 2 modules lets call them A and B for the sake of the argument.

module A:

```
import C from './C';
import { shuffle } from './B';

const A_func = () => new C(shuffle([1, 2, 3, 0]));

export default A_func;
```

module B:

```
...
export const shuffle = (array) => {
  // knuth shuffle algorithm
  // return the shuffled array
};
...

// there are other exports as well
export shuffle;
```

I want to test module A but I would like to spy on the shuffle method that is exported by the module B.

A.spec.js

```
describe('A', () => {
  // no Idea how to create spy on shuffle
  // would like to return a predetermind array as output of shuffle
  // let's say [2, 3, 1, 0]
  // something like (which won't work)
  // spOn('shuffle').and.returnValue([2, 3, 1, 0]);
});
```

Comment: If you want to test that shuffle is called, that belongs in the tests for C.  The only way it would make sense in tests for A is if A, instead of returning a hardcoded function, returned a factory function that could be configured, using dependency injection, with a shuffle function of your choosing, and that factory function returned the *actual* function which you are currently returning.  Then you could pass in mocks and it would make sense.

Comment: The shuffle function is always the same. What I want is to check output of ```A_func```, but I don't wan't the actual implementation of ```shuffle``` to be called.

Comment: From your comments in the post, it sounds like you are trying to mock the shuffle function, so you must rewrite the A function so that you can inject a a mock into it. like so: `const A_func = (shuffle) => () => new C(shuffle([1, 2, 3, 0]));`.  You can also give it a default value of the real (random) shuffle function, so that your client code doesn't have always pass in a real rng.

Comment: hmm..yup that would work but isn't there a way I could achieve the same thing without passing it?

Comment: i'm not sure about that, but you shouldn't *want* to do that.  you should only be testing your public API.  so if you want the ability to inject mocks into you function, it means that configuring your function in that way is part of your public API.  you can always provide *another* public function with the same interface as in your OP, which is created by calling the factory func from my last comment with a default shuffle.  then you'd test the factory func with a mock, and either don't test the convenience func, or simply test that it returns an array of 4 elms or something.

Comment: You make a good point here, but let's say (for the sake of the argument) that the ```shuffle``` function is expensive and I do not want that to be called when running my tests. What should I do in that situation?

Comment: 1) Use a mock and a factory function for the tests, and don't test the convenience function  or 2) decide that you must test the convenience function too, and realize that if you want to test a function that uses an expensive, default shuffle, then you will by logical necessity be committed to calling that in your tests.